# Form redirecting to same page (wrongly and only on IE8)

Tags: html, internet-explorer, web

When submiting a form from a page A it should load a page B but instead of this it redirects to the same page A.

I don't know why but this occurs only in IE8, if I submit the form from mozilla firefox, crome or safari works as expected and loads the page B, even with IE10.

I don't see any reason wich could explain this (beyond cleanning cache without success), any idea?

```
<form action="/b.php" method="post" name="coches" id="buscacoches" class="form_buscar">....
```

Edit: It must be some kind of problem with the cache because I've tried with IE8 from another pc and it worked. But cleanning the cache still does not work with the first one.

Comment: Have you tried putting the full url to **page b** instead of `/b.php` ?

Comment: nope, but I i'm going to try it right now ;)

Comment: I don't have the problematic pc here but will report later

Comment: Ok, I put the full url to page b and now it's working also on that pc. I still don't know wich kind of problem could be with the IE's cache but now all is working. Do you have any explanation of why putting absolute path solves the problem? Thanks anyway!

Comment: To be honest I know sometimes IE can cause strange problems and usually have a simple solution, but I really don't know why it treats absolute paths better.. maybe when you put in b.php it actually goes to http://b.php/ (they might be making their own standards)